# Как работает Scanner.tokens()

Tags: java

В документации к класу Scanner написано, что `tokens()` возвращает стрим стрингов, таких же которые возвращал бы метод `next()`.

Тогда почему здесь `tokens()` возвращает весь текст посимвольно, хотя при использовании `next()` текст делится и возвращается согласно разделителям.

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in).useDelimiter("\\s||\\n");
scanner.tokens().forEach(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Неправильный regex. `\\s||\\n`, Значит что валидные разделители: "\s", "" и "\n". Уберите лишнюю `|`